# Add common Post Actions to Custom Meta Column

Tags: custom-post-types

I've created a custom post section and removed all of the default items (title, editor, etc...) using add_action and added my own custom meta boxes.

The Issue:
Since i've removed the default Title box there's no way to get back into the post since it shows the custom meta box content in custom columns on the top level of the section:
[image: Custom Meta Column Display]

The Question:
How do I add the "Edit | Quick Edit | Trash | View" options to the custom column like WordPress does by default with the Title?

Code being used for section:

```
add_action('init', 'addchic_register');

function addchic_register() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Addy Chicken', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Addy Chicken', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'addchic item'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Convo Item'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Convo Item'),
        'new_item' => __('New Convo Item'),
        'view_item' => __('View Convos Item'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Convos'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        /*'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/article16.png',*/
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('')
      ); 

    register_post_type( 'addchic' , $args );
}
```

Meta boxes:

```
add_meta_box("addy_meta", "Addy", "addy_meta", "addchic", "normal", "low");


function addy_meta(){
  global $post;
  $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
  $addy = $custom["addy"][0];
  ?>
  <input size="100" name="addy" value="<?php echo $addy; ?>" />
  <?php
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an easy way to get that part, it's created in the `_post_row()` function together with the title column. You'll have to copy [that part of the code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.4/wp-admin/includes/template.php#L1342) in your own column callback.

Answer (score 1):

I had not verified this in practice, but basic idea would be to [add custom column](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column) and reuse code from `_post_row()` function that generates actions in it.