# Custom Post Row Actions

Tags: custom-post-types, filters

I came across [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6884/add-common-post-actions-to-custom-meta-column) while writing this question. I have one question that extends upon that question.

I figured out that you use the `get_delete_post_link` filter to create a new url for my actions (or a similar function -- In any case, I'm using that one with the boolean at the end). Only thing is, **I don't know how to capture the event now.** Some help would be appreciated considering I can't find many examples of post row actions on Google. :-/

```
public function _wp_filter_get_delete_post_link( $post_id, $deprecated, $force_delete = false )
{
    if ( ! empty( $deprecated ) )
    {
        _deprecated_argument( __FUNCTION__, '3.0.0' );
    }

    $post = &get_post( $post_id );      
    if ( ! $post ) return;

    if ( strcmp($post->post_type, "visitor") ) return;

    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );
    if ( !$post_type_object ) return;
    if ( !current_user_can( $post_type_object->cap->delete_post, $post->ID ) ) return;
    // http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/post.php?post=163&action=trash&_wpnonce=a56abdcbb3

    $action = ( $force_delete ? 'logout' : 'login' );

    $delete_link = add_query_arg( 'action', $action, admin_url( sprintf( $post_type_object->_edit_link, $post->ID ) ) );

    return wp_nonce_url( $delete_link, "$action-{$post->post_type}_{$post->ID}" );
}
```

And, if you're needing some more information on how I'm using it, here's some more code:

```
public function _wp_post_row_actions( $actions, $post )
{
    if ( $post->post_type == 'visitor' )
    {
        //unset( $actions['edit'] );
        unset( $actions['inline hide-if-no-js'] );
        unset( $actions['trash'] );
        unset( $actions['view'] );

        $state = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'v_state', true ) === 'in';

        if ( $state )
        {
            $actions['trash'] = get_delete_post_link( $post->ID, '', true );    // Logout
            // get_delete_post_link
        }
        else
        {
            $actions['trash'] = get_delete_post_link( $post->ID );  // Login
        }
    }

    return $actions;
}
```

**EDIT:** Well, the above isn't complete. I just noticed that it doesn't actually generate a link which is weird. **So, I guess what I'm asking is for a way to customize the Post Row Actions for my custom post type by adding a "Logout/Login" link in place of the `$actions['trash']` link.**

Comment: Did you ever get a working solution to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main problem is that $actions accepts the whole anchor tag for the link and  get_delete_post_link function outputs just the url.

So if You are just looking to replace the label "Trash" then you can use the post_row_actions filter hook with a simple function

Something like this

```
    add_filter( 'post_row_actions','my_action_row', 10, 2 );
    
    function my_action_row( $actions, $post ){
       if ($post->post_type =="visitor"){
          //remove what you don't need
           unset( $actions['inline hide-if-no-js'] );
           unset( $actions['trash'] );
           unset( $actions['view'] );
           //check capabilites
           $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );
           if ( !$post_type_object ) return;
           if ( !current_user_can( $post_type_object->cap->delete_post, $post->ID ) ) return;
    
          //the get the meta and check
           $state = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'v_state', true );
           if ($state == 'in'){
             $actions['trash'] = "<a class='submitdelete' title='" . esc_attr(__('Delete this item permanently')) . "' href='" . get_delete_post_link($post->ID, '', true) . "'>" . __('Logout') . "</a>";
           }else{
             $actions['trash'] = "<a class='submitdelete' title='" . esc_attr(__('Delete this item permanently')) . "' href='" . get_delete_post_link($post->ID, '', true) . "'>" . __('Login') . "</a>";
    
    
           }
       }
       return $actions;
    }
```

This will generate a logout if the meta is "IN" and login if other wise but both links will delete the post. and i would add a check to see if the post is already in the trash.
But its a start and i hope it helps.

Comment: Now what about capturing the events from the links? How do you do that?

Comment: you can link to your own functions if you want instead of the delete_post_link

Comment: Erm. Brainfart I'm having. :-/ How exactly do I link to my own function?

Answer (score 0):

You can link to your own function like below. I'm passing a url parameter along with the post id, then I'm seeing if that parameter is set, and calling a function based on that. If you want the logout url instead of the custom url, try replacing the anchor with this... 
`<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>`. Obviously you'd have to login to see that 'logout' link, hence I don't see a point in putting a login link over there!

```
add_action('post_row_actions', 'testing');
function testing( $actions, $post )
{
if ( $post->post_type == 'visitor' )
{
    //unset( $actions['edit'] );
    unset( $actions['inline hide-if-no-js'] );
    unset( $actions['trash'] );
    unset( $actions['view'] );

    //Adding a custom link and passing the post id with it
    $actions['customedit'] = '<a href=\''.admin_url('?action=test&post='.$post->ID).'\' target=\'blank\'>Test</a>';
}
return $actions;
}

//Now to get the 'test' argument, and triggering a function based on it...

if($_GET['action'] == 'test')
{
$post_to_print = $_GET['post'];
print_post($post_to_print);
}

function print_post($id)
{
$my_post = get_post($id);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($my_post);
echo "</pre>";
}
```

Let me know if it worked!

Thanks,
Rutwick

Comment: The block of code checking the $_GET['action'] is incorrect?

Comment: $post argument does not exists, your code doesn't work.

Comment: It's an old piece of code! Check BAInternet's answer above.

Comment: jepser I think you just need to pass the accepted args, so the $post can be catched, try use `add_action('post_row_actions', 'testing', 10, 2);`